# ¿Como agregar los caracteres de una frase tipo String en una matriz?

Tags: c#

Necesito dividir los caracteres de una frase y eliminar sus espacios y colocarlos en una matriz, el orden de la matriz dependerá de la cantidad de caracteres de la frase, eh realizado este código pero el error que tengo es que me muestra la ultima letra de la frase en todas las posiciones de la matriz:

```
        char[,] A;
        int orden;
        int x;
        string cadena = txtfrase.Text.Trim();
        orden = int.Parse(cadena.Length.ToString());
        if (orden % 2 == 0)
        {
            x = orden;
            if (orden >= 0)
            {
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    x = (((x * x) + orden) / (2 * x));
            }
            A = new char[x, x];
            for (int i = 0; i < A.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < A.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < cadena.Length; l++)
                        A[i, j] = cadena[l]; 

                }
            }
```

Comment: Saludos Duval, primero lo primero, bienvenido :D, ahora bien, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento adecuado del sitio y de paso obtengas tu ¡primera medalla! Finalmente, sería excelente que coloques un ejemplo del problema que tienes, y ver exactamente dónde te has quedado plantado. De esta manera, tendrás más chances que la hermandad de SOes os ayude a resolver tu pregunta :D

Answer (score 0):

en esta línea le estas indicando justamente eso

```
for (int l = 0; l < cadena.Length; l++)
   A[i, j] = cadena[l];
```

al final del for `A[i, j]` va a contener el último caracter

tendrías que usar un `l` externo a los loops de `i` y `j` e ir incrementándolo a medida de que asignas el valor

onda

```
l=0;
for (int i = 0; i < A.GetLength(0); i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < A.GetLength(1); j++) {
    A[i, j] = cadena[l%cadena.Length]; 
    l++;
  }
}
```

Comment: existe la manera de pasar los caracteres a la matriz pero sin los espacios en blanco y las letras desordenadas?

Comment: seguro, haz un nuevo string/array sin letras y lo desordenas antes de meterlos a la matriz